# Java Creating copy of file before uploading to AWS cloud

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file, selenium-webdriver

I have an image in a directory.
I want to make a copy of that image with a different name without doing harm to the original image in the same directory.
So there will be two same images in one folder with a different name.

I want a basic code like I tried -

```
     File source = new File("resources/"+getImage(0));  
        File dest = new File("resources/");
        source.renameTo("resources/"+getImage(0)+);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I upload the same image to the Amazon server multiple times in automation and then it starts giving issue to upload. 
So we want to upload a mirror copy of image everytime. 
In eclipse generally  have resources folder. I want to make copy of a original image every-time before we upload and delete it after upload.
Kindly suggest some approach

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the file and use [`StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html)

> public static final StandardCopyOption COPY_ATTRIBUTES
>
> Copy attributes to the new file.

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(//path//to//file//and//filename),
    Paths.get(//path//to//file//and//newfilename), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but Instead of handling pop-up box we can directly force file path into the form: [I have used date-stamp for creating new filenames but some different logic could also be used viz- Random String appender etc.]

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class Upload {

    private static final String SRC_RESOURCES_FILE_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/resources/";

    File s1 = new File(SRC_RESOURCES_FILE_PATH+"Img1.png");
    File s2 = new File(SRC_RESOURCES_FILE_PATH+"Img"+getDateStamp()+".png");

    @Test
    public void uploadFunction() throws IOException {
        copyFileUsingJava7Files(s1,s2);

    }

    private String getDateStamp(){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date).toString();

    }


    private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest)
        throws IOException {
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
    }


}
```